# Show currently open folders in Explorer Navigation Pane for ease in saving files to the folder currently working on

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

Is there any script, program, plugin or other that would allow me to save a file to another folder I currently have open on my system.

I work with files located in long folder structures. So I might be working on a project in a folder that is say 10 levels deep like: S://general/projects/2001/Set A/Project-0105/Stage 1/Concept/Revision A/Docs

I will be creating and saving various documents to that folder but each time I create a document and go to save it, the save dialogue box starts of at the default Documents Folder and I have to explore through all the folders to get to the location to save too. This can take a minute to do.

I know I can add a link to the folder in the quick access menu in the navigation pane of the save dialogue box however there are far too many folders I would want quick access too.
It would be so useful if Windows automatically showed all currently open folders in the navigation pane.

Comment: By "open folders", do you mean that you have open Explorer windows displaying the contents of those folders? If so, why not just copy the folder path from the Explorer window's address bar, and paste that path into the Save dialog?

Comment: Thanks, that is an option alright. Will try to do this. A lot of programs don't seem to use the windows explorer interface for saving files so you cant copy paste address path in many cases but what can you do.